# Facebook App Links Mobile Hosted API doesn' t detect installed app iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, applinks

I am trying to implement Facebook App Links using the Mobile Hosted API. Everything goes smoothly but when I test the App Link URL the app doesn't open even if installed and the URL redirects to the App Store. The custom URL for my app is set properly as when I type the custom scheme inside Safari it does open the app. It seems that something is off but can't tell why.

Here is some data:

The url that I test in the browser is:

```
http://fb.me/780961121977733
```

This is the registered data with the Mobile Hosted API:

```
{
 id = 780961121977733;
  ios =(
     {
      "app_name" = GoPhrazy;
      "app_store_id" = 903559056;
       url = "gophrazy://playerPuzzle/leo3/1420663071896";
     }
  );
}
```

The custom url scheme is registered in the info.plist as:
`gophrazy://`

I thought maybe the app_name case would affect it but I tested that to all lower with no effect.

Anyone has any tips on this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the custom url is registered correctly? If you type gophrazy:// into Safari on the device, does it open your app?

Comment: BTW, I just tried your fb.me url with a sample app and overrode the url scheme to be gophrazy, and it worked as expected for me.

Comment: Hi Ming, Thanks for you help. Yes the custom url works. I tested it exactly as you mentioned. Weird that it doesn't work for me. Is it not supposed to work on the simulator maybe?

Comment: How are you able to test the Facebook app in a simulator?

Comment: I just tested it on the device and it doesn't work either. I think I might be confused. I put the link in safari. I expect the link to open a page and redirect to the app if it's installed. Am I assuming this wrong?

Comment: No. Web pages cannot detect whether an app is installed or not (Safari does not allow that), the best they can do is guess, and it's not a great experience. The app links host url (fb.me url) is meant for you to share on Facebook (the app), or other apps that support app links.

Comment: Oh! I see. That's why it's not working from safari. So if I post that link on facebook it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Url scheme in the info.plist MUST be always defined without leading ://